# Unsupported type tech-list in Android Studio for NFC tech-filter

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, nfc, intentfilter

In Eclipse, this tech-filter.xml works fine,
but in Android Studio it gives error at compile time:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > Path-to-project\app\src\main\res\values\tech_filter.xml: Error: Unsupported type 'tech-list'
```

tech-filter.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
        android:resource="values/tech_filter" />
</activity>
```

Has anyone experienced this problem? Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tech-list is not a value resource. You need to put it under `res/xml/` instead. Thus, the path of your tech_filter.xml needs to be

```
app/src/main/res/xml/tech_filter.xml
```

and the manifest entry for it would look like this:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
    android:resource="@xml/tech_filter" />
```

Comment: @AbrahamPutraPrakasa Great. I wonder, though, why this woked in your Eclipse project...